# Release Notes not picked up my renovate bot

Tags: renovate, release-notes, whitesource

We are using [RenovateBot] (https://docs.renovatebot.com/) for automatic dependency management. We get the Pull requests created automatically, but the PRs don't show the release notes. Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: What kind of dependencies we are talking about? there are different ways how renovate try to resolve the changelog, depending on the manager used. a little bit more specific information would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Release notes fetching is only supported for specific platforms (e.g. Github). If you are interested in the release notes from Github [create a PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) and [configure it](https://docs.renovatebot.com/getting-started/private-packages/#looking-up-release-notes).

The property [fetchReleaseNotes](https://docs.renovatebot.com/configuration-options/#fetchreleasenotes) also has to be set to `true` (=default).

Please note that the release of the dependency must include release notes on Github (e.g. https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/releases/tag/6.14.0)